# How do I identify non-linear increase in time for MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

Below are two queries that I am running. One takes between 75-80 seconds and one that takes 1.0-1.5 seconds. Both of these results show the expected 50 rows of `channel_administrators.channel_partner_id`s. The difference between the faster and slower query is the `SELECT` selecting unique logins from the login table. The login table has 460833 rows and I understand that this should slow down the query. The reason I find this unexpected is that when running this code individually on one `channel_administrators.channel_partner_id` the results come back in about 0.2 to 0.7 seconds for the largest `channel_administrators.channel_partner_id` and for 50 results I wouldn't expect it to take more than 50-seconds.

I would expect that the time increase would be linear at the very worst for the time increase but the time increase seems to be more than that. This non-linear increase makes me feel like I'm doing something (very?) wrong but I don't know how to find out what is wrong with my query. Can anyone tell me why there is a non-linear time increase in this query?

I've included some testing queries that I've run and their latest timings at the bottom of the post.

**Edit:**
I think the best example of this phenomenon is looking at Test 2 and Test 3. These examples are as stripped back as they can get and it shows the running the logic once goes quickly but 50 times goes very very slowly.

**EDIT 2:** I've added more data getting the same results in 6.93 seconds rather than 75+ seconds. For my system I think this is an acceptable result. I will write up an answer to this question now.

80-second query:

```
SELECT 
    info.managed_id,
    info.channel_name,
    info.registered_users, 
    info.new_users, 
    info.active_users, 
    info.coupon_opens
    
FROM channel_administrators

LEFT JOIN (    
    SELECT 
        channel_partners.id AS managed_id,
        channel_partners.name as channel_name,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(users.id) 
            FROM users
            WHERE users.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
        ) AS registered_users,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users.id)
            FROM users
            WHERE users.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
            AND users.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
        ) AS new_users,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT logins.user_id)
            FROM logins
            WHERE logins.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
            AND logins.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
        ) AS active_users,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(coupon_trackings.id) AS coupon_view_count
            FROM coupon_trackings
            WHERE coupon_trackings.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
            AND coupon_trackings.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
        ) AS coupon_opens

    FROM channel_partners
) AS info
ON managed_id = channel_administrators.channel_partner_id

WHERE channel_administrators.user_id = 54184

ORDER BY info.channel_name
```

1.5-second query (Commented out difference):

```
SELECT 
    info.managed_id,
    info.channel_name,
    info.registered_users, 
    info.new_users, 
--     info.active_users, 
    info.coupon_opens
    
FROM channel_administrators

LEFT JOIN (    
    SELECT 
        channel_partners.id AS managed_id,
        channel_partners.name as channel_name,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(users.id) 
            FROM users
            WHERE users.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
        ) AS registered_users,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users.id)
            FROM users
            WHERE users.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
            AND users.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
        ) AS new_users,
--         (
--             SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT logins.user_id)
--             FROM logins
--             WHERE logins.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
--             AND logins.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
--         ) AS active_users,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(coupon_trackings.id) AS coupon_view_count
            FROM coupon_trackings
            WHERE coupon_trackings.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
            AND coupon_trackings.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
        ) AS coupon_opens

    FROM channel_partners
) AS info
ON managed_id = channel_administrators.channel_partner_id

WHERE channel_administrators.user_id = 54184

ORDER BY info.channel_name
```

Below are queries I've used to test individual times on the channels with the largest results.

Test 1: 0.441s - For individual biggest channel:

```
SELECT 
    channel_partners.id AS managed_id,
    channel_partners.name as channel_name,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(users.id) 
        FROM users
        WHERE users.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
    ) AS registered_users,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users.id)
        FROM users
        WHERE users.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
        AND users.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
    ) AS new_users,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT logins.user_id)
        FROM logins
        WHERE logins.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
        AND logins.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
    ) AS active_users,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(coupon_trackings.id) AS coupon_view_count
        FROM coupon_trackings
        WHERE coupon_trackings.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
        AND coupon_trackings.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
    ) AS coupon_opens

FROM channel_partners

WHERE channel_partners.id = 3255770
```

Test 2: 0.368s - Active users for the biggest channel:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT logins.user_id)
FROM logins
WHERE logins.channel_partner_id = 3255770
AND logins.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
```

Test 3: 75.2s Just login information

```
SELECT 
    info.managed_id,
    info.channel_name,
    info.active_users    
FROM channel_administrators

LEFT JOIN (    
    SELECT 
        channel_partners.id AS managed_id,
        channel_partners.name as channel_name,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT logins.user_id)
            FROM logins
            WHERE logins.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
            AND logins.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
        ) AS active_users

    FROM channel_partners
) AS info
ON info.managed_id = channel_administrators.channel_partner_id

WHERE channel_administrators.user_id = 54184
```

Test 4: 6.93s - Making Progress with rewrite

```
SELECT 
    channel_partners.id AS managed_id,
    channel_partners.name as channel_name,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(users.id) 
        FROM users
        WHERE users.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
    ) AS registered_users,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users.id)
        FROM users
        WHERE users.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
        AND users.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
    ) AS new_users,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT logins.user_id)
        FROM logins
        WHERE logins.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
        AND logins.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
    ) AS active_users,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(coupon_trackings.id) AS coupon_view_count
        FROM coupon_trackings
        WHERE coupon_trackings.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
        AND coupon_trackings.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
    ) AS coupon_opens

FROM channel_partners

WHERE (channel_partners.id IN (SELECT 
        channel_administrators.channel_partner_id
    FROM channel_administrators
    WHERE channel_administrators.user_id = 54184
    )
)
```

EDIT:
Adding results from queries (removed names)

80s query:

```
|managed_id|registered_users|new_users|active_users|coupon_opens|
|----------|----------------|---------|------------|------------|
|14        |1146            |46       |282         |893         |
|27        |2159            |48       |206         |635         |
|15        |2039            |68       |490         |2560        |
|16        |15              |0        |1           |0           |
|20        |1391            |53       |413         |1614        |
|21        |3               |0        |0           |0           |
|43        |1051            |36       |255         |1234        |
|44        |706             |19       |85          |276         |
|46        |16              |0        |4           |8           |
|47        |68              |1        |5           |30          |
|48        |169             |6        |40          |308         |
|49        |408             |13       |118         |434         |
|52        |52              |1        |11          |54          |
|53        |378             |11       |111         |391         |
|54        |34              |1        |5           |57          |
|75        |576             |7        |59          |145         |
|3255347   |773             |12       |99          |167         |
|685131    |142             |0        |9           |91          |
|76        |22              |0        |9           |25          |
|55        |276             |5        |68          |251         |
|56        |2232            |79       |534         |1644        |
|57        |78              |0        |10          |47          |
|58        |708             |10       |109         |364         |
|59        |1274            |42       |465         |1929        |
|60        |133             |0        |37          |97          |
|3         |0               |0        |127         |257         |
|2144749   |0               |0        |4           |40          |
|61        |629             |9        |119         |363         |
|63        |857             |36       |267         |892         |
|64        |49              |1        |13          |21          |
|65        |723             |15       |281         |1152        |
|66        |77              |0        |17          |48          |
|67        |123             |10       |59          |190         |
|68        |693             |8        |191         |387         |
|70        |80              |0        |31          |58          |
|71        |214             |1        |41          |102         |
|72        |104             |2        |23          |49          |
|3255770   |3149            |86       |542         |2280        |
|3255771   |3012            |39       |526         |2056        |
|77        |180             |9        |89          |239         |
|477       |677             |5        |286         |583         |
|478       |335             |191      |235         |2226        |
|479       |162             |12       |51          |159         |
|480       |57              |0        |8           |12          |
|302       |51              |3        |17          |32          |
|303       |213             |37       |116         |598         |
|373109    |9               |3        |6           |4           |
|373110    |10              |2        |5           |0           |
|373111    |29              |9        |16          |29          |
|3255810   |0               |0        |0           |0           |
```

2s query:

```
|managed_id|registered_users|new_users|coupon_opens|
|----------|----------------|---------|------------|
|14        |1146            |46       |893         |
|27        |2159            |48       |635         |
|15        |2039            |68       |2560        |
|16        |15              |0        |0           |
|20        |1391            |53       |1614        |
|21        |3               |0        |0           |
|43        |1051            |36       |1234        |
|44        |706             |19       |276         |
|46        |16              |0        |8           |
|47        |68              |1        |30          |
|48        |169             |6        |308         |
|49        |408             |13       |434         |
|52        |52              |1        |54          |
|53        |378             |11       |391         |
|54        |34              |1        |57          |
|75        |576             |7        |145         |
|3255347   |773             |12       |167         |
|685131    |142             |0        |91          |
|76        |22              |0        |25          |
|55        |276             |5        |251         |
|56        |2232            |79       |1644        |
|57        |78              |0        |47          |
|58        |708             |10       |364         |
|59        |1274            |42       |1929        |
|60        |133             |0        |97          |
|3         |0               |0        |257         |
|2144749   |0               |0        |40          |
|61        |629             |9        |363         |
|63        |857             |36       |892         |
|64        |49              |1        |21          |
|65        |723             |15       |1152        |
|66        |77              |0        |48          |
|67        |123             |10       |190         |
|68        |693             |8        |387         |
|70        |80              |0        |58          |
|71        |214             |1        |102         |
|72        |104             |2        |49          |
|3255770   |3149            |86       |2280        |
|3255771   |3012            |39       |2056        |
|77        |180             |9        |239         |
|477       |677             |5        |583         |
|478       |335             |191      |2226        |
|479       |162             |12       |159         |
|480       |57              |0        |12          |
|302       |51              |3        |32          |
|303       |213             |37       |598         |
|373109    |9               |3        |4           |
|373110    |10              |2        |0           |
|373111    |29              |9        |29          |
|3255810   |0               |0        |0           |
```

Comment: Pls include the results of explain for both queries, otherwise it is very difficult to see what could have gone wrong!

Comment: I've added markdown tables.

Comment: I've added tests in the middle of the post. Test 2 and test 3 really showcase the stripped back problem.

Comment: I've added 'test 4' getting the login results down to 6.93s. I think this might resolve my issue but need to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each table needs this **composite** index with the columns in the given order:

```
INDEX(channel_partner_id, created_at)
```

And DROP the corresponding index on just `channel_partner_id` if you have such.

Add this "**covering**" index to `channel_administrators`

```
INDEX(user_id, channel_partner_id)
```

and get rid of `INDEX(user_id)` if it exists.

**Simplify** the query by not having nested Selects:

```
    SELECT  cp.id AS managed_id,
            cp.name as channel_name,
            (   SELECT  COUNT(users.id)
                    FROM  users
                    WHERE  users.channel_partner_id = cp.id 
            ) AS registered_users,
            ((etc))
        FROM  channel_partners AS cp
        JOIN  channel_administrators AS ca
                ON cp.managed_id = ca.channel_partner_id
        WHERE  ca.user_id = 54184
        ORDER  BY  channel_name
```

**Tip**:  Consider changing

```
created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
```

to

```
    created_at >= '2021-06-03'
AND created_at  < '2021-06-03' + INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

or use `+ INTERVAL 1 MONTH` if more appropriate.

If you still have **performance** issues, let's see what the query looks like *and* provide **`SHOW CREATE TABLE`**.

Comment: Hi sorry. I was sick yesterday and didn't check this out. I understand the date select is bad way of doing this. I was actually going to be getting the date string from a form on a webpage so currently the way the date is done is WIP. Thank you for that suggestion. I am going to try to implement your solution now.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why this was running slow but I have found a solution that increased the speed and will show the steps on how I got there.

Firstly, in test 2 two and test 3 in the original question, you can see that the individual query to the logins table was pretty quick, but when querying multiple `channel_partner_id` the entire query became very slow. I suspected that it was to do with how I was checking the `channel_partner_id` against the logins table.

I rewrote the query to get the `channel_partner_id`'s from a list instead of from a select. The end result looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    channel_partners.id AS managed_id,
    channel_partners.name as channel_name,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(users.id) 
        FROM users
        WHERE users.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
    ) AS registered_users,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users.id)
        FROM users
        WHERE users.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
        AND users.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
    ) AS new_users,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT logins.user_id)
        FROM logins
        WHERE logins.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
        AND logins.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
    ) AS active_users,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(coupon_trackings.id) AS coupon_view_count
        FROM coupon_trackings
        WHERE coupon_trackings.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id
        AND coupon_trackings.created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-03' AND '2021-07-03' -- 30 days
    ) AS coupon_opens

FROM channel_partners

WHERE (channel_partners.id IN (SELECT 
        channel_administrators.channel_partner_id
    FROM channel_administrators
    WHERE channel_administrators.user_id = 54184
    )
)
```

This query took 6.93 seconds which is still pretty slow but it's much closer to the time that I expected the query would take.

I can't explain why one way is faster and one way is slower.

Comment: I am still new to stack overflow, do I mark my own answer as solved?